# "line 65: Runtime exception at 0x004000ec: invalid or unimplemented syscall service: 97 " why isn't it working?

Tags: mips

I'm writing a mips program that should be playing a song but it isn't working.

```
.data
buffer: .asciiz ""
fin: .asciiz "Over_the_Horizon.mp3"      #nom du fichier en input
loadMusic: .word 0

                                        #LECTURE/ENREGISTREMENT DU FICHIER

.text

fichier:
li $v0, 13                              #appel system pour ouvrir le fichier
la $a0, fin                             #on entre le nom du fichier
li $a1, 0                               #ouvrir le fichier pour le lire
li $a2, 0
syscall
move $s6, $v0                      #enregistrer la description du fichier

li $v0, 14                              #appel système pour lire le fichier
move $a0, $s6                     # description fichier
la $a1, buffer                       #adresse de buffer d'ou lire le fichier
la $a2, 200000                    # longueur/espace de buffer
syscall                                  #lire depuis le fichier

li $v0, 16                               #appel système pour fermer le fichier
move $a0, $s6                      #description fichier pour fermer
syscall                                  #fermer le fichier

                                       #LECTEUR DE SON

playsong:
li $t0, 0

channelStart:
lb $t1, buffer($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
li $t2, 0

chgmtChannel1:
bge $t2, $t1, play
li $v0, 88
lb $a0, buffer($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
lb $a1, buffer($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
syscall
addi $t2, $t2, 1
j chgmtChannel1

play:
li $t1, 0
li $v0, 97
lb $a2, buffer($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
lb $a0, buffer($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
lb $a3, buffer($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
sub $sp, $sp, 4
sw $t4 , 0($sp)
jal readMusic
lw $t4, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 4
addi $t0, $t0, 1
la $a1, ($t4)
syscall
sub $sp, $sp, 4
sw $t4 , 0($sp)
jal readMusic
lw $t4, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 4
addi $t0, $t0, 1
beqz $t4, play
li $v0, 32
la $a0, ($t4)
syscall
j play

                                                   #

readMusic:
lb $t1, buffer($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
lb $t2, buffer($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
lb $t3, buffer($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
lb $t4, buffer($t0)
sll $t4, $t4, 0
sw $t4, loadMusic
sb $t3, loadMusic
lw $t4, loadMusic
sll $t4, $t4, 0
sw $t4, loadMusic
sb $t2, loadMusic
lw $t4, loadMusic
sll $t4, $t4, 0
sw $t4, loadMusic
sb $t1, loadMusic
lw $t4, loadMusic
jr $ra
```

when i'm trying to execute the program it shows me this:

> Error in /home/sokhna1109/projet_son/playson line 65: Runtime
>   exception at 0x004000ec: invalid or unimplemented syscall service: 97
>
> Go: execution terminated with errors.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:

```
li $v0, 97           <-- $v0 = 97
lb $a2, buffer($t0)  \
addi $t0, $t0, 1      |
lb $a0, buffer($t0)   |
addi $t0, $t0, 1      |
lb $a3, buffer($t0)   |
addi $t0, $t0, 1      | 
sub $sp, $sp, 4       | none of this modifies $v0
sw $t4 , 0($sp)       |
jal readMusic         |
lw $t4, 0($sp)        |
addi $sp, $sp, 4      |
addi $t0, $t0, 1      |
la $a1, ($t4)        /
syscall              <-- syscall, uses $v0 for the system call number
```

And presumably the simulator you use does not implement any system call 97.

Comment: thank you! But if i write " li $v0, 37 " instead (and " li $v0, 38 " on line 40), it still doesn't work since it doesn't play the song.

Comment: can you, please, tell me why ?

Comment: System calls 37 and 38 are not available in any MIPS simulators that I'm aware of, but you haven't mentioned what your target environment is. I've definitely never heard of any MIPS-based system that has system calls for MP3 playback.

Comment: `$v0` is how MIPS figures out which syscall to use. If you set `$v0` to a value that doesn't correspond to any functions, then it's going to go... somewhere. Where does it go? Who knows?